# I can ping my PLC but cannot add route in TwinCat

Tags: connection, plc

Automation beginner here. I will try to be as clear as possible even though I do not have the background.

In my lab, there is a test bench. We acquire data from sensors (Temperature, torque, speed, distance). This data passes through a PLC, which is itself linked to an HMI.

We have a problem since a few days with the connection between the HMI and the PLC so we want to take a closer look at the program inside the PLC. But we cannot add it to the routes it TwinCat.

[image]

- I have tried to add it from 2 different computers
- I am able to ping the PLC, and I am able to access it by typing its IP in a browser
- I have tried both from a PC within the same subnet, and from a PC directly linked via ethernet to the PLC

Both the PLC and the HMI are old (2009). The communication problem might comes from a change we made in the HMI program, which updated the PLC driver to a version which is too recent?

I don't really know what to do next. Is there any magic trick that would allow me to connect to the PLC and retrieve the program from it?

Comment: Did you try to use a newer version of TwinCAT engineering software?

Comment: I believe I am using the latest version. I have not been able to put my hands on an older one

Comment: What happens if you try to connect to the PLC when it is in config mode? Depending on your device, it might have dip switches to force it to go to config upon powerup.

Comment: I have not tried that. Is there any chance the program could be lost? We do not have a backup and it would be a disaster

Comment: It would only start in config mode. As long as boot project was uploaded to the PLC you are fine. You can always copy the SD card contents just in case.